# Impact of Upgrading razor version 1.2 to 1.3

Tags: 2011, razormediator

I just want to upgrade razor v1.2 to 1.3.

when I run razor v1.3 setup on SDl Tridion2011 SP1, it does not provide upgrade option and through an error message that another version is already installed.

So if i uninstall the current version and install Razor v1.3 will there be any impact on existing templates?

Answer (score 5):

I have not had to upgrade the Razor mediator yet.  However, with the recent memory leak fixes, in v1.3.3 I will probably be doing this soon.

The upgrade should just be a matter of uninstalling v1.2 and then re-installing v1.3.

The steps that I would probably take are:

1. Take the CMS (CME and Core Service) offline to prevent users from trying to publish (or open templates) during the upgrade.
2. Back up the Tridion CM database (may be being over cautious here)
3. Make a backup of the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file (the documentation says that this is done automatically during the uninstall, but you can never be too careful!)
4. Uninstall version 1.2
5. Restart the Tridion Content Manager COM+ Package, the Tridion Publisher service, and Template Builder (if it’s open).
6. Install version 1.3.3 ([it contains memory leak fixes](http://codedweapon.com/2013/06/razor-mediator-version-1-3-3-released/) over 1.3)
7. Re-instate any imports or configuration changes in to the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file that you may need
8. Restart the Tridion Content Manager COM+ Package, the Tridion Publisher service, and Template Builder (if it’s open).
9. Test (including publishing)
10. Make the CMS available again.

You will want to do this in development, before moving it up through the DTAP environments.

You may want to consider the amends to the functionality between 1.2 and 1.3.3 in the [Razor Mediator Change Log](https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/wiki/ChangeLog) whilst testing.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

The process of upgrading the Razor Mediator is to uninstall it and then install again.  I would suggest to make a copy of the Razor configuration settings at the bottom of your Tridion.ContentManager.config file before uninstalling the 1.2 version.  The good news is the 1.3 version patches a memory leak that would require restarting the Publisher service on a regular basis.  Question:  Do you use imports form the config file or in the template?